# How to simplify fallowing martrices' Expected value elements in the equation

Tags: expected-value, covariance-matrix, matrix, matrix-inverse

I have a matrix equation with four variables inside, $x^1_{00}$, $x^1_{tt}$ and $x^2_{tt}$, $x^2_{tt}$. $x^1_{00}$, $x^1_{tt}$ come from the same distribution , they are only shifted by timelag $t$. The same goes for $x^2_{tt}$, $x^2_{tt}$. Also both are mean-free (their mean is zero).

I have a matrix equation as fallowing
$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
E[x^1_{00} x^1_{00}] & E[x^1_{00} x^2_{00}] \\
E[x^2_{00} x^1_{00}] & E[x_{00}^2 x^2_{00}] 
\end{bmatrix}^{-1/2}
\begin{bmatrix}
E[x^1_{00} x^1_{tt}] & E[x^1_{00} x^2_{tt}] \\
E[x^2_{00} x^1_{tt}] & E[x_{00}^2 x^2_{tt}] 
\end{bmatrix}  
\begin{bmatrix}
E[x^1_{tt} x^1_{tt}] & E[x^1_{tt} x^2_{tt}] \\
E[x^2_{tt} x^1_{tt}] & E[x_{tt}^2 x^2_{tt}] 
\end{bmatrix}^{-1/2} $$

What I want to achieve is to simplify elements inside the matrices:
e.g.
$E[x^1_{tt} x^1_{tt}]$ and $E[x^1_{00} x^1_{00}]$ can be noted as $\sigma^2(x^1_{00})$, and the same goes for $x^1_{00}$ so:

$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma^2(x^1_{00}) & E[x^1_{00} x^2_{00}] \\
E[x^2_{00} x^1_{00}] & \sigma^2(x^2_{00}) 
\end{bmatrix}^{-1/2}
\begin{bmatrix}
E[x^1_{00} x^1_{tt}] & E[x^1_{00} x^2_{tt}] \\
E[x^2_{00} x^1_{tt}] & E[x_{00}^2 x^2_{tt}] 
\end{bmatrix}  
\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma^2(x^1_{00}) & E[x^1_{tt} x^2_{tt}] \\
E[x^2_{tt} x^1_{tt}] & \sigma^2(x^2_{00}) 
\end{bmatrix}^{-1/2} $$

But the rest is quite hard for me to simplify and can't identify with high certainty elements, that could be reduced to the same variable.

Comment: Could you explain why you duplicate every subscript in your notation?  I suspect if you were to disclose the statistical application, it would help all readers interpret the meaning of your formula and thereby suggest a (huge) simplification.  Incidentally, which square roots of these matrices do you have in mind?  The usual symmetric ones?